# Confused with CountedCompleter's sample code fragment in java8 doc

Tags: java, forkjoinpool

I read java8 doc about [CountedCompleter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountedCompleter.html), which gives sample usage code as follow:

```java
 class MyOperation<E> { void apply(E e) { ... }  }

 class ForEach<E> extends CountedCompleter<Void> {

   public static <E> void forEach(E[] array, MyOperation<E> op) {
     new ForEach<E>(null, array, op, 0, array.length).invoke();
   }

   final E[] array; final MyOperation<E> op; final int lo, hi;
   ForEach(CountedCompleter<?> p, E[] array, MyOperation<E> op, int lo, int hi) {
     super(p);
     this.array = array; this.op = op; this.lo = lo; this.hi = hi;
   }

   public void compute() { // version 1
     if (hi - lo >= 2) {
       int mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
       setPendingCount(2); // must set pending count before fork
       new ForEach(this, array, op, mid, hi).fork(); // right child
       new ForEach(this, array, op, lo, mid).fork(); // left child
     }
     else if (hi > lo)
       op.apply(array[lo]);
     tryComplete();
   }
 }
```

In `compute` method, Every ForEach object will fork two subtasks and set pending count to 2,
but in the end of `compute` method, `tryComplete` can only decrement one in pending count, how
does the rest one??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading source code of `ForkJoinPool` and `CountedCompleter`, I finally understand it.

All CountedCompleters derived from root CountedCompleter will be organized like a tree. When you call `tryComplete`, if current pending count is positive,  it will decrement 1. Otherwise it will call `onCompletion` of current CountedCompleter, then recursively call `tryComplete` on parent CountedCompleter. If parent CountedCompleter is `null`, it means it is already root CountedCompleter, then the whole task complete.

So we know that:

- `CountedCompleter` task will not end after `compute()` method is done, it will wait until pending count decrements to 0
- `CountedCompleter` task isn't always ended by root task itself (very different from `RecursiveTask` and `RecursiveAction`), it can be ended by childs' `tryComplete`

Then let's see the code fragment in java 8 doc (note sequence number 0: 1: 2: 3: in code, it is one possible execute order):

```java
 class MyOperation<E> { void apply(E e) { ... }  }

 class ForEach<E> extends CountedCompleter<Void> {

   public static <E> void forEach(E[] array, MyOperation<E> op) {
     new ForEach<E>(null, array, op, 0, array.length).invoke();
   }

   final E[] array; final MyOperation<E> op; final int lo, hi;
   ForEach(CountedCompleter<?> p, E[] array, MyOperation<E> op, int lo, int hi) {
     super(p);
     this.array = array; this.op = op; this.lo = lo; this.hi = hi;
   }

   public void compute() { // version 1
     if (hi - lo >= 2) {
       int mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
       setPendingCount(2); // 0: +2
       new ForEach(this, array, op, mid, hi).fork(); // 2: -1
       new ForEach(this, array, op, lo, mid).fork(); // 3: pending count == 0 complete
     }
     else if (hi > lo)
       op.apply(array[lo]);
     tryComplete();  // 1: -1
   }
 }
```